# Absolute DIVs position().left in respect to immediate relative parent?

Tags: html, css, positioning, css-position

I have a child div `"child"` whose position is absolute. Its parent `p1` has relative positioning. Also p1 has a parent `p2` whose positioning is also relative.

So when I get child's position().left its in respect to p1 or p2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`p1`, since its `child`'s closest non-statically positioned ancestor.